# Apply a function to a column - wikipedia retrieve data

Tags: r

Hello Stack Overflow community
I am trying to retrieve article data from wikipedia using below code

The issue is that it does not encapsulate the result of the function in the data frame.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(glue)
library(XML)
library(RCurl)

# Function

wiki_data <- function(data,end_url="Tensorflow"){

  html <- getURL(glue("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{end_url}"), followlocation = TRUE)

  # parse html
  doc = htmlParse(html, asText=TRUE)
  plain.text <- xpathSApply(doc, "//p", xmlValue)
  cat(paste(plain.text, collapse = "\n"))
}

#Creation of data frame

df <- data.frame(items=c("Tensorflow","Data"))

#Applying the function
df %>% 
  mutate(test=wiki_data(items,end_url = items))
```

The results would be the data frame with two columns one items the other items with the result from the function (wikipedia results).
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Just remove `cat`, it's printing the output of `paste`, not returning it to caller. Also, when you use functions not in base R, start the scripts with calls to `library()` to load the necessary packages. (I have done it already.)

Comment: You need to vectorize your function `wiki_data`, AFAIK `mutate` does not iterate the function over the column of values.

Comment: Thanks a million @RuiBarradas for your time and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function does not return anything. You could save the results in `res`. Further, you do not need the `data` argument in the function. I assume you used the `RCurl` and `XML` libraries.

```
wiki_data <- function(end_url){
    require(XML)
    require(RCurl)
    require(glue)
    html <- getURL(glue("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{end_url}"), followlocation = TRUE)

    # parse html
    doc <- htmlParse(html, asText=TRUE)
    plain.text <- xpathSApply(doc, "//p", xmlValue)
    res <- paste(plain.text, collapse = "\n")
    return(res)
}
```

It's not the most elegant solution, but it should work.
Then you can use `rowwise()` to apply your function:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(test = wiki_data(items))
```

Comment: I did. The function always returned the value of the first row of the items col.

Comment: Thanks @dasds - Yes indeed I loaded the library but did not integrate it in the code- thanks for pointing it out.